# How can I restart mono-Modules in iOS for Unity?

Tags: ios, mono, unity-game-engine

I would like to restart the engine Unity on the iPhone. For this purpose we have adapted to the `AppController`. We use the `Unitycleanup` function to quit Unity. But if we start the `Unity InitApplication` function a second time, then the application crashes. We have now noticed that there is a problem with the `RegisterAllStrippedInternalCalls` function. Therefore, the question of how you can disable the mono-modules?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the crash? Stack trace perhaps?

Comment: here is the crash report from Mono: Mono path[0] = '/var/mobile/Applications/4C305E0B-6621-4A8C-AC41-7DF693B5E35A/XXXX.app/Data/Managed' * Assertion at critical-sections.c:61, condition `ret == 0' not met –